# why cuda to device variable transfer gives noncontiguous error?

Tags: cuda, numba

I am new to cuda and trying to calculate a matrix using gpu. 
The idea is to use the thread index and block index to locate different piece of memory of two different matrix. Calculate the matrix block by block and then copy it back to the corresponding output matrix.

The code is like:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def GPU_SimpleOp(dim1, dim2):
    x = dim1 + dim2
    return x

@cuda.jit
def GPUCore(nd_matrix1, nd_matrix2, nd_output):

    blockix = cuda.blockIdx.x
    threadix = cuda.threadIdx.x

    if blockix > nd_matrix1.shape[0] or threadix > nd_matrix2.shape[0]:
        return

    nd_output[blockix, threadix] = GPU_SimpleOp(nd_matrix1[blockix], nd_matrix2[threadix])


def Test(nd_matrix1, nd_matrix2, blockno=256, threadno = 256):
    cuda.pinned(nd_matrix1)
    cuda.pinned(nd_matrix2)

    dim1 = nd_matrix1.shape[0]
    dim2 = nd_matrix2.shape[0]
    output = np.ndarray(shape=[dim1, dim2])
    nd_output = np.ascontiguousarray(output)
    cuda.pinned(nd_output)

    blocks_dim1 = int(math.ceil(dim1 / blockno))
    thread_dim2 = int(math.ceil(dim2 / threadno))

    for i in range(blocks_dim1):
        dim1_s = i
        dim1_e = min((i + 1) * blockno, nd_matrix1.shape[0])
        for j in range(thread_dim2):
            dim2_s = j
            dim2_e = min((j + 1) * threadno, nd_matrix2.shape[0])

            stream = cuda.stream()

            device_mat1 = cuda.to_device(nd_matrix1[dim1_s:dim1_e], stream)
            device_mat2 = cuda.to_device(nd_matrix2[dim2_s:dim2_e], stream)
            device_output = cuda.to_device(nd_output[dim1_s:dim1_e, dim2_s:dim2_e], stream)
            GPUCore[blockno, threadno, stream](device_mat1, device_mat2, device_output)

            device_output.copy_to_host(nd_output[dim1_s:dim1_e, dim2_s:dim2_e], stream)
            stream.synchronize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dim1 = 1000
    dim2 = 5000
    nd_matrix1 = np.random.random(dim1)
    nd_matrix2 = np.random.random(dim2)
    blockno = 256
    threadno = 256

    Test(nd_matrix1, nd_matrix2, blockno, threadno)
```

When I run this code, I got an error:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 201.7846.77)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 127, in ensure_context
    yield
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 225, in _require_cuda_context
    return fn(*args, **kws)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\api.py", line 110, in to_device
    to, new = devicearray.auto_device(obj, stream=stream, copy=copy)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 692, in auto_device
    sentry_contiguous(obj)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 666, in sentry_contiguous
    raise ValueError(errmsg_contiguous_buffer)
ValueError: Array contains non-contiguous buffer and cannot be transferred as a single memory region. Please ensure contiguous buffer with numpy .ascontiguousarray()
```

The code failed at the line `device_output = cuda.to_device(nd_output[dim1_s:dim1_e, dim2_s:dim2_e], stream)`. 
Even though I googled the answer and tried to use `nd_output = np.ascontiguousarray(output)`. It still does not work. 
Any help please?

Comment: The array slices are not contiguous. Make a new array from the slices and transfer that to the device

Comment: @talonmies thanks, I made a new array and it works. But it still confuse me why ```device_mat1 = cuda.to_device(nd_matrix1[dim1_s:dim1_e], stream)``` works but the nd_output doesn't work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a modification to the code according to talonmies' suggestions.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def GPU_SimpleOp(dim1, dim2):
    x = dim1 + dim2
    return x

@cuda.jit
def GPUCore(nd_matrix1, nd_matrix2, nd_output):

    blockix = cuda.blockIdx.x
    threadix = cuda.threadIdx.x

    if blockix > nd_matrix1.shape[0] or threadix > nd_matrix2.shape[0]:
        return

    nd_output[blockix, threadix] = GPU_SimpleOp(nd_matrix1[blockix], nd_matrix2[threadix])


def Test(nd_matrix1, nd_matrix2, blockno=256, threadno = 256):
    cuda.pinned(nd_matrix1)
    cuda.pinned(nd_matrix2)

    dim1 = nd_matrix1.shape[0]
    dim2 = nd_matrix2.shape[0]
    output = np.ndarray(shape=[dim1, dim2])
    nd_output = np.ascontiguousarray(output)
    cuda.pinned(nd_output)

    blocks_dim1 = int(math.ceil(dim1 / blockno))
    thread_dim2 = int(math.ceil(dim2 / threadno))

    for i in range(blocks_dim1):
        dim1_s = i * blockno
        dim1_e = min((i + 1) * blockno, nd_matrix1.shape[0])
        for j in range(thread_dim2):
            dim2_s = j * blockno
            dim2_e = min((j + 1) * threadno, nd_matrix2.shape[0])

            stream = cuda.stream()
            device_mat1 = cuda.to_device(nd_matrix1[dim1_s:dim1_e], stream)
            device_mat2 = cuda.to_device(nd_matrix2[dim2_s:dim2_e], stream)
            new_array = np.zeros_like(nd_output[dim1_s:dim1_e, dim2_s:dim2_e])
            device_output = cuda.to_device(new_array, stream)
            GPUCore[blockno, threadno, stream](device_mat1, device_mat2, device_output)

            device_output.copy_to_host(new_array, stream)
            nd_output[dim1_s:dim1_e, dim2_s:dim2_e] = new_array
            stream.synchronize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dim1 = 1000
    dim2 = 5000
    nd_matrix1 = np.random.random(dim1)
    nd_matrix2 = np.random.random(dim2)
    blockno = 256
    threadno = 256

    Test(nd_matrix1, nd_matrix2, blockno, threadno)
```

It now works. But it still confuses me. Why `device_mat1 = cuda.to_device(nd_matrix1[dim1_s:dim1_e], stream)` works, but `device_output = cuda.to_device(nd_output[dim1_s:dim1_e, dim2_s:dim2_e], stream)` doesn't work?

Comment: Slicing in more than one axis produces non-contiguous view of memory which can't be used directly in buffer protocol calls. Copy the slice to a temporary array and then copy that to the device